# convert hash to array of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How simply convert a hash to an array of key/value ?

```
my %h;
%h{1} = 11;
%h{2} = 22;
```

and I want an array @result which I could represent as : `[ { 1 => 11 }, { 2 => 22} ]` (yes like in json to be clear)

Comment: Perl's hashes map straightforwardly to JSON dictionaries. Transforming a perfectly good dictionary to a list of single-item dictionaries is as unnatural in JSON as it is in Perl.

Comment: Did you mean `$h{1} = 11;`?

Comment: In fact to_json() can do this too, "=>" become just ":"     
`push(@arr, \%h);`    
`printf "%s\n", to_json(\@arr)`

Comment: yes Shawn error $h{1} = 11; etc ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one.

```
my @h = map { { $_ => $h{$_} } } keys %h;
```

Comment: thanks, yes the hash is splitted in several hashes in any case

Comment: this will produce an array with the keys in an arbitrary order; if the keys are always numeric, you probably want `map { { $_ => $h{$_} } } sort { $a <=> $b} keys %h` and otherwise `map { { $_ => $h{$_} } } sort keys %h`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the built in `List::Util` library's excellent [`pairmap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#pairmap) function.

```
use List::Util qw< pairmap >;

my @array_of_pairs = pairmap { { $a => $b } } %some_hash;
```

Even if you don't use this function today, take some time to check out [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util), there is a lot of good stuff in there.